# ASP.NET Core Custom Authorization & Memory Cache

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am implementing a program that Caches all Roles by combining them with CustomAuthorize. It is a page-based authorization.
In the customAuthorize Class I couldn't figure out how to access CacheHelper.cs via ICacheHelper.

This is CacheHelperClass

```
public class CacheHelper : ICacheHelper
{
    private readonly IMemoryCache memCache;
    private readonly IConfiguration configuration;
    public CacheHelper(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this.memCache = (IMemoryCache)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IMemoryCache));
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }

    public async Task<List<RoleTreeListViewModel>> GetRoleTreeListViewModel()
    {
        var cacheList = memCache.Get<List<RoleTreeListViewModel>>("RolTree");
        if (cacheList == null)
        {
            var model_list_result =
                await new RoleTreeRepository(configuration).GetAllRoleTreeForAuthorization();
            cacheList = model_list_result;
            memCache.Set("RolTree", model_list_result);
        }
        return cacheList;
    }
```

This is ICacheHelper class

```
 public interface ICacheHelper
{
    public Task<List<RoleTreeListViewModel>> GetRoleTreeListViewModel();
```

Now, CustomAuthorize where I stuck.

```
 public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private  ICacheHelper cacheHelper;        
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext authorizationFilterContext)
    {
        cacheHelper = new CacheHelper()//I cannot call it here


        cacheHelper.GetRoleTreeListViewModel();
        Task<List<RoleTreeListViewModel>> oParentRoleTreeList =  cacheHelper.GetRoleTreeListViewModel();
        Task<List<Item>> oParentItemList =  cacheHelper.GetItemList();
        Task<List<Role_ItemListViewModel>> oParentRoleItemList =  cacheHelper.GetRole_ItemList();
        string filePath = authorizationFilterContext.HttpContext.Request.Path;
        string hataSayfasi = "~/Account/Login?returnUrl=" + filePath;
        string queryString = string.Empty;
        var request = authorizationFilterContext.HttpContext.Request;
```

Startup.cs;

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddTransient<ICacheHelper, CacheHelper>();
        services.AddMemoryCache();
```

Comment: Could you try to get the CacheHelper as follows: 
`var cacheHelper = authorizationFilterContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(ICacheHelper)) as ICacheHelper`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For resolving dependencies in an `AuthorizeAttribute` you can use the `AuthorizationFilterContext` to get your services.

You can use the following snippet in `CustomAuthorizeAttribute`:

```
public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext authorizationFilterContext)
{
    var cacheHelper = authorizationFilterContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(ICacheHelper)) as ICacheHelper;
}
```